# Обновление textbox после нажатия radiobutton

Tags: c#, winforms

Я хочу сделать чтобы после нажатия на radiobutton значение Enabled у textbox менялось с false на true. Как это сделать? Пытался сделать так, но не получилось

```
if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
{
    textBox1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: textBox1.Enabled  = radioButton4.Checked == true;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте событие [RadioButton.CheckedChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private void radioButton4_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton4.Checked == true)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую завтра

Answer (score 3):

Вот так намного короче можно сделать тоже самое.

```
radioButton1.CheckedChanged += (sender, arg) => 
       textBox1.Enabled = ((RadioButton) sender).Checked;
```

Соответственно если нужно обратное поведение, то достаточно добавить инверсии.

```
textBox1.Enabled = !((RadioButton) sender).Checked
```

[image: принцип работы]